# Chaining Tk::BrowseEntry widgets together

Tags: perl, combobox, widget, tk-toolkit

I am facing some glitches using the -browsecmd and -listcmd options of Tk::BrowseEntry widget:

I have three BrowseEntry widgets and each uses the value of the previous one as input for populating its own list. The values are used as arguments to a subroutine that pulls out the list of items in the drop-down list from a flat file database. The subroutine calls the insert method on the widget to populate its choices.

The problem is this:

When I change the first BrowseEntry widget's value, the next BrowseEntry widget which uses the former's value to populate its own list *appends* the new list to the old list instead of replacing it. I heard this is a known bug, so I called the delete function but to no avail.

Does anyone know of a workaround that will solve this problem?

Comment: Does it work any differently if you invoke delete on the listbox subwidget instead?  E.g. `$browseEntry->Subwidget('slistbox')->delete(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I get this Error:
Tk::Error: Can't call method "Subwidget" on an undefined value

I need a way for the subroutine associated with each widget to be called each time the drop down list is 'activated'. And the subroutine must use the current value of the previous widget's value as its argument to give the most updated list...

Any help/pre-baked solutions to the above problem will be greatly appreciated.